# Varied Constructor Dependency Injection based on Interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Say I have this:

```
public class Human : SentientLifeForm, IHuman {
    IBreathingService breathingService = null;

    public Human(IBreathingService breathingService) {
        this.breathingService = breathingService
    }
}

public class Martian : SentientLifeForm, IMartian {
    IBreathingService breathingService = null;

    public Martian(IBreathingService breathingService) {
        this.breathingService = breathingService
    }
}
```

Then I have two different implementations of the BreathingService...

```
public class HumanBreathingService { ... }
public class MartianBreathingService { ... }
```

How can I use DI to pass the correct service implementation to the associated object? Or do I have to specify an IHumanBreathingService and an IMartianBreathingService?

Comment: What context is this? .NET Core?

Comment: Are you *using* DI?  If so, which?

Comment: Autofac for now, but if there are containers that allow for this, please let me know.

Comment: Probably .NET Core, yes.

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288872/autofac-how-to-create-a-generated-factory-with-parameters already answers this. Autofac enables this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Autofac - How to create a generated factory with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288872/autofac-how-to-create-a-generated-factory-with-parameters) already answers this.

Autofac enables the ability to create a factory for creating the correct service.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks specificity therefore I will explicitly explain the assumption I am making.

Assumption 1:  SentientLifeForm implements IBreathingService.

Assumption 2:  HumanBreathingService and MartianBreathingService implement/derive-from IBreathingService.

Assumption 3:  *HumanBreathingService* will be passed to the constructor for *Human* as a parameter and MartianBreathingService will be passed to the constructor for *Martian* as a parameter.  **THIS IS THE DI IN THIS PROJECT**.

Thereafter, say you have a method SolarSystemBeing(..) that takes as an argument an instance of SentientLifeForm.  Then depending on which instance it gets a Human or a martian the breathingService will be the appropriate one...